# Crash system Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, physics

I'm making car game in unity3d, I have city, cars, street lamps etc. I want to make it destroyable, like in GTA. For now its working like it should be, but problem is with resistance of some object, for example traffic lights or lamps, objects which are concreted.

Here is picture which is describing it:
[image]

Here is my script, its really easy and its working in low speed (<60-70kmh):

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    PlayerSpeed = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f;
    PlayerMass = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass;
    PlayerKineticEnergy = (PlayerMass * PlayerSpeed * PlayerSpeed) / 2;

    if (PlayerKineticEnergy > 900000.0f)
    {
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
        StreetBehaviour = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Street_Asc_Behaviour>();
        CollisionSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt((2 * 900000) / (PlayerMass));
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * (-CollisionSpeed * StreetBehaviour.ObjectResistance), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

As you can see, im using freeze position and rotation in rigidbody, its working very well in low speed. In high speed it doesnt detect collision.

So if you have better one, it would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: I would just create a script that stores the object's resistance and put it on every breakable prefab and then in your driving script check during the crash if you had enough speed to break the object u crashed into.

Comment: i tried, but problem is, that my speed during crash is lower and not so high like before crash. So script can detect only lower speed and here is my problem. I added collider to lamp, change size (bigger) and check isTrigger, so script can detect, if car is near lamp and get his actuall speed, then when crash happen can calculate everything. Problem is, that OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter are slow or something, because Im getting late reactions

Comment: ok so I tried a lot of ways and one si working for me, problem is high speed. While car has speed <60-70kmh it works great, but if speed is more than 70kmh it doesnt work at all and there are glitches :D so i need high speed detection or new script